# Axios on NodeJS will not log into a session but from Postman it will

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a login command that will work from a browser or will work from Postman, but will not work from Axios in nodejs. I even copied the code from Postman to get it right.

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://xtone.buf.vaspian.net/webadmin/en/user/jsp/ProcessLogin.jsp?tenantWebName=%2FSomeCompany&UserID=999&Password=999',
  headers: { 
    'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=' + uuid() +'; langCode=en; tenantUrl=/SomeCompany'
  }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I get back that the 'Session has expired'.

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Something doesn't look right because this is a POST request, but you are putting the data in the url (like you would for a GET url) and there's no body data at all for the POST.  So, if this is really supposed to be a POST, then the password data probably belongs in the body of the POST, not in the url.  If you show the POSTMAN request that "works", that might help.

Comment: It also looks invalid that the client-side code is making a new sessionID.  That should be something the server does, not the client.

Comment: the instructions told me to use a POST rather then a GET for security reasons. I ahve done this both ways and same result. I also have disabled the headers and got the same result.

Comment: Well, for security reasons, you would NEVER put userID and password in the URL.  If you're being instructed to use a POST for security reasons, then the username and password belong in the body of the request, not in the URL.